# If some columns of $XA, A$ are equal, does it mean $XA=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on a problem related to the row space $R(A)$ of a matrix $A \in K^{k \times n}$, where $k < n$. This space is invariant under a left-action of $GL(k, K)$ on the matrix $A$.

Say I have two matrices with identical row spaces. Then they must fall in the same orbit of this action, so I may take $XA, A$ for some $X \in GL(k, K)$. I'm trying to work out if $XA, A$ are equal on some non-empty subset of columns $I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$, that it then holds that $X$ is the identity, i.e. $XA = A$.

I suspect it is true, especially if $|I|$ is big enough, but I'm kind of at a loss for how to prove it, or where to look. Can anyone provide me with some references or some keywords of where to look for material that deals with these kinds of problems? 
I'm also interested in the case when $X \in GL(k, L)$ for some extension field $L \supseteq K$.

Comment: For example when $A$ is diagonal and $X$ is a diagonal matrix differing from $I_k$ at a single position, then $XA$ and  $A$ share $n-1$ columns, but are not equal.

Comment: Aren't you talking about $A X$ instead of $X A$?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&2\cr}\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&2&0\cr}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&4&0\cr}.$$ The 2x3 matrices $A$ and $XA$ share the first and last columns.